# In the Poincare disk, there exist points $A$ and $B$ on the same side of line $L$ such that no circle through them lies entirely on that side

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I am attempting this problem using Poincare disk.

> I want to show for hyperbolic plane (using this Poincare disk), there exists 2 points $A$, $B$ lying on same side $S$ of line $L$ such that no circle through $A$, $B$ lies entirely within $S$.

**My Attempt**

I know  hyperbolic circles in the Poincare disk model are also Euclidean circles -  except that P-centers differ from Euclidean circle  when the center is not O.
It follows that for this reason, P-centers are closer (in a Euclidean sense) to the boundary circle than expected in the Euclidean case.

Accordingly, given any line L, I choose arbitrary points A,B such that A,B are close to the boundary and the line L. It remains to show that any circle through A,B intersects line L.

[image]

I am wondering if the reasoning is correct and how I could complete/improve it.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a simple hand-sketch?

Comment: @Narasimham I updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Hint: Find $A$ and $B$ such that the smallest Euclidean circle through them is tangent both to $L$ and to the Poincaré boundary. (For convenience, take $L$ to be a "diameter" of the Poincaré disk.)

Comment: @Blue I followed through this idea, I choose midpoint of AB, then drawing a perpendicular to the midpoint that hits L, to give point P. Now I have A,B,P tI could o construct euclidean circle through them. But this is euclidean circle, for the hyperbolic circle the center  is different - there is an offset. Will this them imply point P has to be on the other side.

Comment: @koolaids: I'm not sure I understand your description. Let me be more clear, myself. Let the Poincaré boundary be the unit circle with center $O$. Let $L$ join $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ (so it's the "horizontal diameter"). Consider a Euclidean circle that is both tangent to $L$ at $O$ and tangent to the boundary circle. (The latter tangency keeps it from being a *hyperbolic* circle.) Choose $A$ and $B$ on that circle in a fairly natural way, and then it should be straightforward to show that any other Euclidean circle through them will extend past $O$ or else break through the Poincaré boundary.

Comment: @Blue I got that analysis. Thank you. But what of points different from O. That is, what  if it is tangent to L at other points?

Comment: @Blue you mentioned the later tangency keeps it from being a hyperbolic circle: is this because we have an open disk?

Comment: @koolaids: For these kinds of exercises, you're allowed to pick convenient elements. After all, you're just trying to find *some* $A$ and $B$ the the desired property. That said, you can have the circle be tangent anywhere along $L$; getting the exact (Euclidean) radius to make it tangent to the disk boundary is a little trickier, but it's doable. (Of course, it's sufficient to know that such a radius exists.)

Comment: @koolaids: And, yes: the openness of the disk keeps a Euclidean circle tangent to the boundary from being a hyperbolic circle (instead, it's called a *horocycle*). This is often precisely the key to solving these kinds of exercises. A straightforward Euclidean circle construction corresponds to a somewhat exotic non-Euclidean result because the Euclidean circles in the Poincaré model represent so many different types of non-Euclidean elements (circles, lines, horocycles, or hypercycles) depending upon how they relate to the Poincaré boundary.

Answer (score 1):

A benefit of the Poincaré disc model is that it is embedded in the Euclidean (equivalently, complex) plane and we are free to use the latter's geometry (equivalently, algebra).

Any line in $\mathbb{D}^2$ can be mapped isometrically onto the segment of the imaginary-axis cutting the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$, so WLOG take $L$ to be this "vertical" diameter of $\mathbb{D}^2$.

Choose any $z=x+iy\in\mathbb{D}^2$ such that the perpendicular-bisector between $z$ and the origin $O$ intersects the real-axis outside the disc, and $\lvert x\rvert \lt \lvert y\rvert$.
Figure $1$ shows the unique circle $C$ that goes through $z,O,\overline{z}$.

[image]
$\tag{Figure 1}$

Any circle through $z,\overline{z}$ whose centre lies to the right of $L$ in the above figure will clearly intersect $L$ and, by our choice of $y$, any circle whose centre lies on the interval $[x,0]$ will also intersect $L$, since the radius must be greater than $\lvert x \rvert$. Hence we need only consider circles centred on $(-\infty,x)$.

Figure $2$ shows what happens to the circle through $z, \overline{z}$ when you shift the centre of $C$ to the left or the right, i.e. any blue-shift circle no longer touches $L$ and any red-shift circle intersects $L$ in two points, which can be proved by an application of the $\mathbb{E}^2$-triangle inequality. But this means every circle through $z,\overline{z}$ of $\mathbb{E}^2$-radius $r\lt 1$, which includes all $\mathbb{D}^2$-circles through those points, must intersect $L$, and so we have found the necessary $A,B$ satisfying the criteria. $\qquad\square$

[image]

$\tag{Figure 2}$

Answer (score 0):

*Comment*

Why is placement of circles these ways not possible?

[image]

Comment: I could make a guess. It has to cut through the arc to fit the definition of lines as circular arc  meeting unit circle at right angles in the model under consideration. Right?

Comment: @Narasimham: Take $A$ and $B$ arranged "horizontally" on your large red (Euclidean) circle. Any other (Euclidean) circle would extend either upward (beyond the Poincaré boundary, in which case it doesn't represent a hyperbolic circle) or downward (in which case it *does* represent a hyperbolic circle, but it necessarily crosses line $L$). Importantly, the large red circle itself, being tangent to the Poincaré boundary, doesn't itself represent a hyperbolic circle. Thus, no hyperbolic circle through the "horizontal" $A$ and $B$ is contained entirely within region $S$.

Comment: Ok, Basically would like to see a Wikipedia on hyperbolic circles defined and built on  the Poincaré model apart from geodesics that are orthogonal to the boundary.

Comment: We can map the upper half-plane onto the Poincaré disc by Euclidean inversions and reflections, and hence $\mathbb{D}^2$ inherits its metric from the $\mathbb{H}^2$-metric $dz/\lvert Im z\rvert$. From there we can use the fact that in $\mathbb{H}^2$ the distance between points $i$ and $iB$ is $\lvert \log B\rvert$, and that $\mathbb{E}^2$-rotations are isometries in $\mathbb{D}^2$, to show that the set of equidistant points from the origin $O$ in $\mathbb{D}^2$ are $\mathbb{E}^2$-circles centred at $O$ of radius $r\lt 1$...

Comment: ...Moving back and forth between $\mathbb{H}^2$ and $\mathbb{D}^2$ you can thus show that the sets of points equidistant from a given point in either model are Euclidean circles in either space (although their centres are not necessarily the same). See Stillwell (1992) for more details.